# Why float += operator leaves out integer?

Tags: integer, operator-keyword

Hey there I'm using libGDX and I have following problem, just can't see what I'm doing wrong:

I have

```
float generatingTime = 0;

if (generatingTime < 1.0f){
   generatingTime =+ 0.01f)
   }

if (generatingTime == 1.0f){
   objectState.state = objectState.GENERATED;
   }
```

Somehow my float generatingTime never is exactly "1.0f".
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for helping guys!

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: `=+` is obfuscating. Please put a space between the symbols. As for your question, not all numbers can be represented exactly in a `float`. Can you not scale your time unit by 100 and use an integer?

Comment: Is the `=+` a typo? It's `+=` in the question title.

Comment: And `0.01f)` is a typo tool I guess. Should be `0.01f;`.

Comment: For that matter, how is `generatingTime` ever greater than `0.01f`? You set it to zero, then add once, then test `if (generatingTime == 1.0f)`. Maybe there are even more typos in the code?